# Parse JSON with leading underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I `console.log` my data, it looks like this in Chrome Dev Tools:

```
e.LatLngBounds {_southWest: e.LatLng, _northEast: e.LatLng}
    _northEast: e.LatLng
        lat: 50.62507306341435
        lng: -69.169921875
      __proto__: Object
    _southWest: e.LatLng
        lat: 27.059125784374068
        lng: -127.96875
       __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

If I `JSON.stringify` it (like so: `var totbounds = JSON.stringify(mybounds);`), I get this:

```
{"_southWest":{"lat":27.059125784374068,"lng":-127.96875},"_northEast":{"lat":50.62507306341435,"lng":-69.169921875}}
```

I'm trying to parse it to get the `_southWest` `lat` (for example), but neither of these work:

```
totbounds[_southWest][lat];
totbounds._southWest.lat;
```

(Note, `totbounds` is the stringified object)

Comment: If you stringify the object, you get a JSON string, not an object. You should read the properties from the object, not the string. Use `mybounds._southWest.lat`.

Comment: Try this: http://jsbin.com/lumeqemaza/1/watch?js,console

Comment: I think you want `mybounds._southWest.lat` or `mybounds['_southWest']['lat']`

Comment: How did you parse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` **converts your JavaScript object to string so you can't access it as object like you tried**. Stringified JSON is not an object you can access its property. The object should remain object, not stringified. You don't need it in your purpose (if I understand your problem correctly).

Given:

```
var mybound = {_southWest: e.LatLng, _northEast: e.LatLng}
_northEast: e.LatLng
    lat: 50.62507306341435
    lng: -69.169921875
  __proto__: Object
_southWest: e.LatLng
    lat: 27.059125784374068
    lng: -127.96875
   __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

To access its property, you can do via:

```
var lat = mybound["_southWest"]["lat"];
```

Comment: Thanks. I forget the quotes.

Comment: @jonmrich: You don't need quotes. `mybounds._southWest.lat;` works just as well. Your only mistake was to convert the object to  a string. Always read the documentation before you use an unfamiliar method, saves you a lot of guessing.

Comment: @FelixKling Your suggestion is correct. People have two choices of accessing their object properties. Thanks for adding this, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If mybounds is your object, you can just do

```
mybounds._southWest.lat;
```

---

Example:

```
var str = '{"_southWest":{"lat":27.059125784374068,"lng":-127.96875},"_northEast":{"lat":50.62507306341435,"lng":-69.169921875}}';

var mybounds= JSON.parse(str);
console.log(mybounds._southWest.lat);
```

> 27.059125784374068